# Is it possible to handle cache in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, aurelia

Here am using , tiff reader library from client side to convert tiff file to image for user view.User will see only one at a time, provided pagination to see next/prev one, here, while user paginating each time hit server to get the tiff and render it as image on screen. 
**see code :**

```
var costructUrl = 'http://cdn.dmsapp.tk/'+appUrl+'/'+evt+'?authToken='+this.getuserservice.authorizationfun()+'&force=false'; xhr.open('GET', costructUrl);   xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var pages = [];
            var buffer = xhr.response;
            var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});
            var len = tiff.countDirectory();
            var currentPage = index;
            if (currentPage < len) getTiff();function getTiff(){
                tiff.setDirectory(currentPage);
                var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                pages.push(canvas.toDataURL()); if ((currentPage+1 < len && currentPage < limit)) {
                    currentPage++;
                    getTiff();         // get next page
                }
                }
            }
        };xhr.send();
```

My question is, Is it possible to store the **xhr.responce** in cache, to prevent server hit every time. [image: see pagination inside redmark]

Comment: ServiceWorkers.

Comment: Yes, it's possible on modern browsers with [service workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/). It's non-trivial, but not **hard** per se...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can handle cache in javascript very easily.

You can Use `localStorage` to store anything to cache, It uses key value pair to store value and it will be available to all the pages of your domain. The value will persist even if the browser is closed. Unlike `sessionStorage` which stores value as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores.

To write to localStorage use

```
localStorage['yourKey'] = 'yourValue';
```

To Read data use

```
var stored = localStorage['yourKey'];
```

The value will be visible to all the pages of the same domain from which the value was written.

Yes, You can store any string value to the cache.

If you want to store a object you can use

`localStorage['yourKey'] = JSON.stringify(your_obj);`  and store the value

and later parse the value to get object

`your_obj = JSON.parse(localStorage['yourKey'])`;

For More Information [Check Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)